# I cannot locate the bad setState in the error: Cannot update a component (`aaa`) while rendering a different component (`bbb`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was trying to restructure my code, setting up a new component that iterates and displays a list, this list will be reusable hence I created the component. but while trying to run it, I got he  `Cannot update a component (MoneyIn) while rendering a different component (ItemLists). To locate the bad setState() call inside ItemLists, follow the stack trace as described in` which made why web browser to freeze. The link provided was just a forum discussion on GitHub.  There have been a whole lot of suggestion on how useEffects can be helpful here, but I guess my code is quite a different case.

Here is the code:

```
//Parent Component
const MoneyIn = () => {
const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);

 let handleSaveItem = () => {
        const newItemData = { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, sellingPrice };
        setNewItems([...newItems, newItemData]);
        console.log(newItemData);
    }
   const displayAddedItemList = () => {
        if (!visible) {
            totalSellingPrice = newItems.reduce((total, item) => total + parseFloat(item.sellingPriceOfTotal), 0);
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>Items</div>
                    <ItemLists newItems={newItems} handleDelete={handleDelete}/>
                    <div className='totalItemsAdded'>
                        <p>Total</p>
                        <p>${totalSellingPrice}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}


//Child Component

const ItemLists = (props) => {
  
    const newItems = props.newItems;
    const handleDelete =  props.handleDelete();
   
  return (
 

    <div>
        
         {newItems.map((items) => {
                        const { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, sellingPrice } = items;
                        return (
                            <>
                                <div className='itemsAdded'>
                                    <div className='eachItemAdded'><div>{productName}</div>
                                        <div>{sellingPriceOfTotal} = {sellingPrice} x {quantityCount}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='deleteEditFont'><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} onClick={() => handleDelete(items)} /></div>

                                </div>

                            </>
                        );
                    })}

    </div>
     

  )
}

export default ItemLists
```

Comment: You are calling `handleDelete` every time the `ItemLists` renders (`const handleDelete =  props.handleDelete()`). I think you wanted `const handleDelete =  props.handleDelete`

Comment: wow!! it worked . Konrad, you can highlight it lemme mark it as answer.

Comment: ps. You can also do -> `const {handleDelete} = props;`  If you do it that way, your less likely to accidentally invoke the function too.